# Do you sometimes omit "what" in the "No matter what + noun ~" structure?

Tags: usage

Do you sometimes omit "what" in the "No matter what + noun ~" structure? I came across one, and I want to make sure the omission is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

There should be "what", "where", "how" etc. after "no matter":

> You use *no matter* in expressions such as 'no matter how' and 'no matter what' to say that something is true or happens in all circumstances (from the Collins Dictionary).

Examples:

No matter **what** your age, you can lose weight by following this program.

No matter **how** often they were urged, they could not bring themselves to join in.

Jenkins would reward all investors, no matter **when** they made their investment.

BUT if after "no matter" there is just a noun or a noun phrase, then we can use "no matter" without any question words:

- No matter the age, a child is a child.
- No matter the condition, this jacket is my treasured possession.

Note that it would be **incorrect** to say **No matter often** they were urged... BUT you it's **OK** to say No matter what your age (is) or No matter your age, ... (because there is a noun phrase after "no matter", there is no verb, or there can be the verb to be but it's omitted).

Comment: https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/world-news/waitress-pays-firefighters-bill-repay-6199490

Comment: So, "No matter your role, ~" is not grammatical, right?

Comment: @Nofear yeah, good point. See my edited answer.